# How to run custom codeunit when user uninstalls custom extension

Tags: dynamics-business-central

We have an extension that creates a Job Queue Entry to ensure that custom table values based on certain rolling dates stay in sync. The extension also creates some PermissionSets. When the extension is uninstalled, the Job Queue Entry needs to be deleted and the PermissionSets need to be removed from any users to which they were assigned.

The Codeunit class exposes a Subtype property but the non test values are only Normal, Insert and Upgrade. I was expecting an Uninstall and/or Unpublish Codeunit as well.

How do I detect a user extension uninstall so I can remove the items in question?

Comment: Uninstalling the extension removes the Job Queue entry because it relies upon a code unit that is part of the extension. The permissions were not removed, but were blanked out (e.g everything is a blank except the actual permission name). Now they are in limbo, they cannot be deleted or reactivated.

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for does not exist at the moment. It is on the product backlog as far as I know.

There are several issues on Github where people request the feature:

[Issue 191](https://github.com/microsoft/AL/issues/191)

[Issue 1271](https://github.com/microsoft/AL/issues/1271)